# Run spring boot app with gradle with bootRun using arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have the following fragment in build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.12.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
..
bootRun {
   systemProperties = System.properties
}
..
```

I run the app using following command.

```
./gradlew bootRun -PjvmArgs=-Dserver.port=8090
```

However it doesn't work. What should I change to run app with specified port like I have done that in application.properties.

```
server.port=8090
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the configuration you have this should work:

```
./gradlew bootRun -Dserver.port=8090
```

With this piece of code:

```
bootRun {
   systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

you pass `System` properties to the application that will be run. `-P` is for project property.

Comment: The same way for datasource and server.contextpath ?